# what is proper elasticsearch date format for my date 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +5:30'? I need exact format so that i can query this date in DSL query

Tags: date, elasticsearch, timezone, mapping

My source data field 'insert_date' has mapping defined as type: 'date' format : 'yyyy-MM-dd' and values like '2010-12-29 23:21:24 +05:30'. I want to filter my data on this column using DSL query with below filter. { "query": { "range": { "LOAD_DATE_TSP": { "gte": "2017-08-04 11:00:00 +5:30", "lt": "2019-08-04 12:00:00 +5:30" } } } }

for above filter to work, i need mapping that matches with my data - '2010-12-29 23:21:24 +05:30'. I have applied mapping suggested on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html. but no luck :(. Please suggest.

EXPECTED result - DSL query should display data between "2017-08-04 11:00:00 +5:30" & "2019-08-04 12:00:00 +5:30"

error i am got after trying yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ format - "error": { "root_cause": [ { "type": "parse_exception", "reason": "failed to parse date field [2017-08-04 11:00:00 +5:30] with format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ]"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for your mapping to try the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +5:30` instead of  `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ`

I tried to reproduce your senario and it works fine:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @bugsb. but this is not giving me expected output.mapping changed as per your input.
"timestamp_fltr_test": {
"aliases": { },
"mappings": {
"timestamp_fltr_test": {
"properties": {
"LOAD_DATE_TSP": {
"type": "date",
"ignore_malformed": true,
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +5:30"

data in my index
LOAD_DATE_TSP
2019-07-31 15:40:40 +5:30
2018-07-31 15:40:40 +5:30
2017-07-31 15:40:40 +5:30
DSL Query i am using. 
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "LOAD_DATE_TSP": {
        "gte": "2017-08-04 11:00:00 +5:30",
        "lt": "2019-08-04 12:00:00 +5:30"

Comment: output of DSL query.
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 0,
"max_score": null,
"hits": [ ]
}
}

Comment: try to add `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +5:30"` so it will be: `"query": { 
 "range": { 
  "LOAD_DATE_TSP": { 
   "gte": "2017-08-04 11:00:00 +5:30", 
   "lt": "2019-08-04 12:00:00 +5:30",
   "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +5:30"
  }
 }
  }`

Comment: Thanks @bugsb. I added format qualifier in DSL query but still its giving empty output.

Comment: thanks @bugsb. when i used get method for _search operation, elasticsearch displays all the records. .i.e. filter is not working. when i used post for _search it shows null. in other cases we use post method for _search and it display correct result in those cases. my elastic version is 5.1.1